# My button is only ever using the value of the text box when it is first pressed

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a array of custom **Task** structs called **taskArray** in my to-do list app that contains the tasks for today.
I also have a **nextTaskToBeAdded** variable that represents the next **Task** to be added to the list.

In my app, there is a TextField for the name of **nextTaskToBeAdded** and a Button to append **nextTaskToBeAdded** to **taskArray**.

The Button works for the first press, correctly using the value in the TextField, but on other presses (even if the TextField contents have changed) will still use that first value.

Here is the code for my button and TextField

```
TextField("Next task's name", text: $nextTaskToBeAdded.name)
                    
Button {
    taskArray.append(nextTaskToBeAdded)
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "plus")
}
```

Here is the code for the list

```
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Today's Tasks:")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                List(taskArray) { task in
                    TaskView(taskToShow: task)
                }
            }
```

And here is the code for the variables

```
            @State var taskArray: [Task] = [
        Task(name: "Do the dishes", completed: false,priority: 3),
        Task(name: "Code app", completed: true, priority: 1)]
    
    @State var nextTaskToBeAdded: Task = Task(name: "", completed: false, priority: 4)
```

I have tried to use the debugger and expected to see that **nextTaskToBeAdded** was not receiving the new value in the text box, however it was getting the new value, yet an outdated value was used.

**EDIT:**
Here is the task declaration:

```
struct Task: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    var name: String
    var completed: Bool
    var priority: Int
}
```

Comment: I'm very new to stack overflow, so should I be putting this in the comments or editing my question? Also is what I've put not a minimal example, or is it just non-reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your `Task` uses a `UUID` as its `id`. This is only generated when you call the initialiser.

The initialiser is only called 3 times in your code - twice in the existing tasks’ array, and once for `nextTaskToBeAdded`.

Using the text field, the user can change the name of `nextTaskToBeAdded`, but not its `id`, so you are adding a task with the same `id` into the array every time the user taps the add button, and so `ForEach` thinks they are the same.

I would use a simple `String` to store the name of the next task. Create a *new* task in the button action, so that the `id` gets generated again.

```
Button {
    // here you call the initialiser, which generates a new UUID
    let nextTaskToBeAdded = Task(name: nextName, completed: false, priority: 4)
    taskArray.append(nextTaskToBeAdded)
} label: {
    ...
}
```

Where `nextName` is a `String` `@State`, controlled by the text field.

```
@State var nextName = ""
...

TextField("Next task's name", text: $nextName)
```

It also works if you want to identify a task with its name instead,

```
var id: String { name }
```